# Google Vision Api supports PDF nad TIFF text detection but can it work with PDf containing images as well?

Tags: api, pdf, google-cloud-platform, vision

I am trying with a pdf containing images as well with google vision API but it throws the following error :

> 4:35:12.207 pm info    dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment Dialogflow Request
>   headers:
>   {"host":"us-central1-detecttext-5a0c3.cloudfunctions.net","user-agent":"Apache-HttpClient/4.5.4
>   (Java/1.8.0_181)","transfer-encoding":"chunked","accept":"text/plain,
>   */*","accept-charset":"big5, big5-hkscs, cesu-8, euc-jp, euc-kr, gb18030, gb2312, gbk, ibm-thai, ibm00858, ibm01140, ibm01141,
>   ibm01142, ibm01143, ibm01144, ibm01145, ibm01146, ibm01147, ibm01148,
>   ibm01149, ibm037, ibm1026, ibm1047, ibm273, ibm277, ibm278, ibm280,
>   ibm284, ibm285, ibm290, ibm297, ibm420, ibm424, ibm437, ibm500,
>   ibm775, ibm850, ibm852, ibm855, ibm857, ibm860, ibm861, ibm862,
>   ibm863, ibm864, ibm865, ibm866, ibm868, ibm869, ibm870, ibm871,
>   ibm918, iso-2022-cn, iso-2022-jp, iso-2022-jp-2, iso-2022-kr,
>   iso-8859-1, iso-8859-13, iso-8859-15, iso-8859-2, iso-8859-3,
>   iso-8859-4, iso-8859-5, iso-8859-6, iso-8859-7, iso-8859-8,
>   iso-8859-9, jis_x0201, jis_x0212-1990, koi8-r, koi8-u, shift_jis,
>   tis-620, us-ascii, utf-16, utf-16be, utf-16le, utf-32, utf-32be,
>   utf-32le, utf-8, windows-1250, windows-1251, windows-1252,
>   windows-1253, windows-1254, windows-1255, windows-1256, windows-1257,
>   windows-1258, windows-31j, x-big5-hkscs-2001, x-big5-solaris,
>   x-compound_text, x-euc-jp-linux, x-euc-tw, x-eucjp-open, x-ibm1006,
>   x-ibm1025, x-ibm1046, x-ibm1097, x-ibm1098, x-ibm1112, x-ibm1122,
>   x-ibm1123, x-ibm1124, x-ibm1166, x-ibm1364, x-ibm1381, x-ibm1383,
>   x-ibm300, x-ibm33722, x-ibm737, x-ibm833, x-ibm834, x-ibm856,
>   x-ibm874, x-ibm875, x-ibm921, x-ibm922, x-ibm930, x-ibm933, x-ibm935,
>   x-ibm937, x-ibm939, x-ibm942, x-ibm942c, x-ibm943, x-ibm943c,
>   x-ibm948, x-ibm949, x-ibm949c, x-ibm950, x-ibm964, x-ibm970,
>   x-iscii91, x-iso-2022-cn-cns, x-iso-2022-cn-gb, x-iso-8859-11,
>   x-jis0208, x-jisautodetect, x-johab, x-macarabic, x-maccentraleurope,
>   x-maccroatian, x-maccyrillic, x-macdingbat, x-macgreek, x-machebrew,
>   x-maciceland, x-macroman, x-macromania, x-macsymbol, x-macthai,
>   x-macturkish, x-macukraine, x-ms932_0213, x-ms950-hkscs,
>   x-ms950-hkscs-xp, x-mswin-936, x-pck, x-sjis_0213, x-utf-16le-bom,
>   x-utf-32be-bom, x-utf-32le-bom, x-windows-50220, x-windows-50221,
>   x-windows-874, x-windows-949, x-windows-950,
>   x-windows-iso2022jp","content-type":"application/json;
>   charset=UTF-8","function-execution-id":"dvrpphf9f855","x-appengine-api-ticket":"4b7e84f29e9ce22b","x-appengine-city":"?","x-appengine-citylatlong":"0.000000,0.000000","x-appengine-country":"US","x-appengine-https":"on","x-appengine-region":"?","x-appengine-user-ip":"35.193.50.245","x-cloud-trace-context":"9d163f59b7fc5d0049692efae5269b4c/11159965978299906802;o=1","x-forwarded-for":"35.193.50.245,
>   35.193.50.245","x-forwarded-proto":"https","accept-encoding":"gzip"} 4:35:12.045 pm outlined_flag  dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment Function
>   execution started 4:32:49.480 pm warning
>   dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment  ERROR: { Error: Error in extracting
>   images from PDF file gs://detecttext-5a0c3.appspot.com/NFM-11099M1.pdf
>       at GoogleError.Error (native)
>       at new GoogleError (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/vision/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/GoogleError.js:46:42)
>       at Operation._unpackResponse (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/vision/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/longrunning.js:228:29)
>       at /user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/vision/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/longrunning.js:214:18
>   code: 13 }

Comment: Seems to me your most likely problem is a broken PDF file, but since you haven't posted the original file, its impossible to tell.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue - in my case, setting `gzip: true` on the upload was causing issues:

```
this.client
    .bucket(bucketName)
    .upload(fullPath, {
        gzip: false,  // setting gzip: true causes the pdf annotator to fail
        metadata: {
            cacheControl: 'no-cache',
        },
    })
    .then(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [PDF/TIFF Document Text Detection](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf#top_of_page) will gather only the text from the PDF, however the error that you're getting seems different as I tried making the request with [this PDF file](https://www.hbp.com/resources/SAMPLE%20PDF.pdf) and had no issues at all.